# two identical simultaneous request treated as one by (?PHP) + cookies

Tags: php, mysql, apache, cookies

I wanted to provide some kind of "transactions" to my PHP website.
Simply, performing two request simultaneously by a logged-in user is undesirable.
At first, I tested my app without any big changes, also just cookies + code unaware of concurrency.
I have added some 
`sleep(15)`
to
`a.php`
and
`b.php`.

Requesting two pages: 
`a.php` 
and then 
`b.php`
causes 30 second of loading, which is expected behaviour due to cookie usage. Cookie is locked by 
`a.php`
 for 15 s, so 
`b.php`
 waits for its 15 s.

However, requesting `a.php`
 twice lasts just 15 s. It seemed that both request are somehow joined.
I added some SQL insert with autoincrement id, and echoed 
`$db -> insert_id`
, which was the same.

I also echoed some GET parameter: requesting 
`a.php?text=One` and 
`a.php?text=Two`
 also lasts 30 seconds, while requesting 
`a.php?text=One`
 twice is once again treated as one.

1.What causes such treatment?
2.Is it reliable that the client cannot perform two request because of this behaviour?
3.If not, how should I restrict user to one instance of a.php at time?

EDIT:
Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["myUser"]) && is_object($_SESSION["myUser"]))
{
    $loggedInUser = $_SESSION["myUser"];
}

sleep(15);

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');      // :)
if($db->connect_errno > 0)
{
    die('Unable to connect to database!');
}

$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO curl (request) VALUES (?)");
//id is inserted by MySQL autoincrement

$request=1;

$statement->bind_param('i', $request);
$statement->execute();

$id = $db->insert_id;   

echo $id;
?>
```

Comment: Show us your code. Hard to tell behaviour without code.

Comment: On 3: build your app in such a way it can robustly handle these things.

Comment: you can try to implement some kind of file lock on the script to make the calls 'concurrent aware', not sure if this is foolproof though as  I too have been looking for such features in PHP

Comment: PHP isn't in charge of the request. The web server is. You are probably getting the response back from your first request.

Comment: @Bart: Requesting the same page twice shows the same id and in the database there is only ONE record added, so second request wasn't processed at all.

Comment: I'd guess that it's simpley browser caching that's responsible for the effect you're seeing. Also please note that it's the session that locks the concurrent requests, not the cookie.

Comment: @Spudley: I think you are right. I tried from second browser and it was possible. I know now that my code fail in this situation. How can I achieve blocking some part of code for a user?